# Finding first occurence of number in a SORTED array recursively

Tags: java, sorting, recursion

I would like to find the first occurence of a given number `x` in a sorted array. This is the method I have so far:

```
public static int firstOccur(int[] A, int x, int start, int end){

    int first = start;
    int last = end;
    int result = -1;

    while (first <= last){
        int mid = (first+last)/2;

        if(A[mid] == x){
            result = mid;   
            firstOccur(A, x, first, mid-1);
            return result;
        }
        else if(A[mid] < x){
            first = mid+1;
            result = firstOccur(A, x, first, last);
        }
        else if(A[mid] > x){
            last = mid-1;
            return firstOccur(A, x, first, last);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the value you are looking for: ");
    int val = sc.nextInt();

    int[] arr = {1,2,2,2,5};
    System.out.println("The first occurence of " + val + " is at index " + firstOccur(arr, val, 0, arr.length-1));

}
```

When I run the code, the function works for numbers `1 & 5 and anything added`. Unfortunately, when submitting `x=2`, it returns index 2, which is not true. Am I missing a small detail?

Comment: You mixed while loop and recursion. One of them is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not considering the return value of the recursive function here

```
if(A[mid] == x){
    result = mid;   
    firstOccur(A, x, first, mid-1);
    return result;
}
```

Change it to

```
if(A[mid] == x) {
    result = mid;   
    int maybeResultToLeft = firstOccur(A, x, first, mid-1);
    if (maybeResultToLeft == -1) {
       return result;
    }
    return maybeResultToLeft;
}
```

Or a one-liner

```
return maybeResultToLeft == -1? result : maybeResultToLeft;
```

We need to pick the element (`x`) to the left of the current (`x`) element (if it exists - `maybeResultToLeft != -1`)

Comment: Why are you returning `Math.min(result, maybeResultToLeft)` if maybeResultToLeft is -1?.

Comment: If there are any other values on the left of the current element, it must be chosen over the current one. (as the `2` in your case)

Comment: If i were to find the last occurence, how would the code look like? `return tempResult == -1 ? result : Math.max(result, tempResult);` ?

Comment: @mendy Actually, there is no need to use min/max, as we go to the left side, any valid index returned (-1) is guaranteed to be lesser than the current index. The same applies for moving right too. I have updated the answer.